# How is Beyond Compare 4 configured for Visual Studio 2019 from the command line?

Tags: git, git-config, beyondcompare4

Scooter Software [specifies](https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#visualstudio-git) that the following settings be *manually* added to Git's config file to integrate Beyond Compare 4 with Visual Studio 2019.  However, how can these settings be generated from the *command line* using 'git config' -or- is this impossible?

```
[diff]
    tool = bc4
[difftool "bc4"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 4\\BComp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[merge]
    tool = bc4
[mergetool "bc4"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 4\\BComp.exe\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\"
```

Comment: It's not *impossible*, but it is exceedingly ugly because of the need to embed both double quotes and backslashes. The commands will be different in bash, cmd.exe, and (I imagine) powershell (though I have not used powershell).

Comment: I agree with @torek, but, you could edit the file manually, confirm it works, save it off, and try to repeat those commands from whatever command line you want to use until you get it to match the file you saved. (And use Beyond Compare to see if they match. Heh.) It may take a little trial and error with the quotes and slashes.